Tuple iteration failed : TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
So I have a nested tuple and I try to run the code above but I have an error:
tup = (((1,2),(3,4),(5,6)))

for sub_tup in tup:    
    for (a,b) in sub_tup:
        print(a)


Do anyone can explain me what's happeing here? I get the error:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

If I do:
for (a,b) in tup:
   print(a)


I won't get the error.
I expect that I can use a nested for loop to acces a nested tuple but is not like that!

You need to remember the trailing comma for single-element tuples, otherwise they don't define a tuple and just act as no-op parentheses:
tup = (((1,2),(3,4),(5,6)),)

for sub_tup in tup:    
    for (a,b) in sub_tup:
        print(a)

prints:
1
3
5

